# Apache2 proxy Tomcat6 prevent 503 error while starting

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6, mod-proxy

While tomcat6 is starting up all my http requests are retained by the server and sends the response when the server is up.

But when I use an apache2 as a proxy the apache2 responds inmediatly a 503 error when the tomcat is starting. How can I prevent this default behaviour of apache proxy?

My apache virtualhost configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:[PORT]>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia full

  <proxy>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </proxy>

  ProxyPass        /[PATH] http://localhost:8080/[PATH2]
  ProxyPassReverse /[PATH] http://localhost:8080/[PATH2]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a possible solution but am not 100% satisfied with it. This seems to work with httpd version 2.2.22.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ maxattempts=1000
ProxyPassReverse / balancher://mycluster/
```

The balancer parameter `maxattempts` sets the number of attempts that the balancer will use while cycling through balancer members and sending them requests while they fail. I'd rather have a solution with a timeout but I haven't found anything that worked other than `maxattempts`.